# CodeIgniter error Questions::$form_validation

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

Hi I am getting an error in codeigniter,

> Message: Undefined property: Questions::$form_validation
>
> Filename: controllers/questions.php
>
> Line Number: 43

My Questions.php controller which is not a default controller BTW.

```
class Questions extends CI_Controller{
  public function user_logged_in(){
    $this->load->library('../controllers/main');
    $obj = new $this->main();
    $status = $obj->logged_in();
    if($status){
        return true;
    }else{
     return false;
     }
   }

   public function validate_question(){
      if($this->user_logged_in()== true){
      $this->load->library("form_validation");
      $this->form_validation->set_rules("input_title","Title","required");
      $this->form_validation->set_rules("message","Description","required");
      $this->form_validation->set_rules("vidya","Description","required");
      if($this->form_validation->run()){
          echo "Form has been Submitted";
      }else{
          $this->load->view('question_posts/post_questions');
      }
   }else{
      redirect('main/index');
   }
 }
}//end of class Questions
```

I have even autoloaded in my config/autoload.php by doing

```
$autoload['helper'] = array("form");
```

Now I dont know why this error is still there. Or is it because I have already loaded a library in user_logged_in() method. Other than that I am so helpless as to why this error happenned.

Comment: Turns out it is the source of the error. the user_logged_in method already loaded a library. Now how to load a form validation in that situation.

Comment: does line number point to `validate_question()` function ?

Comment: Can you do a step by step debugging, e.g for your `user_logged_in` `return false` & then check if the **error persists**.